# Insert XML String into Python dictionary value

Tags: python, php, xml

I've had trouble searching this because there's a lot of "turn xml into a dictionary" posts but that's not what I'm looking for. I have no desire or need to parse the xml string.

I have an xml string that I want to insert into one dictionary element. My dictionary looks like this

```
{'JobName':'Test','JobProgram':'1234','JobParameters':'<xmlString><some have="double quotes" /><theresAlso aPath="\\path\with\(paraenthesis)\goes\here" /></xmlString>'}
```

But that doesn't seem to work as is, I'm guessing it has to do with the <> and double quotes. So what do I need to do?

My end goal is to send all this as a POST command to URL.php using the `requests` library in python. URL.php then uses htmlspecialchars($JobParameters), so I'm not fully sure I know what it expects as input either, raw xml or stripslashes(xml) or something else. I can read but cannot edit the php file.

Comment: Explain what does it mean: "But that doesn't seem to work as is..."

Comment: As it stands, I can't get the xml string into a dictionary value, I get errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON [does not accept single quotes](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml#Double_Quotes) surrounding key names and values.
Double quotes (`\"`) and literal backslashes (`\\`) must be escaped inside a value.

Using double quotes and testing on command line with `jq`

```
echo '{"JobName":"Test","JobProgram":"1234","JobParameters":"<xmlString><some have=\"double quotes\" /><theresAlso aPath=\"\\path\\goes\\here\" /></xmlString>"}' | jq -r '.'
```

Result (meaning valid Json):

```
{
  "JobName": "Test",
  "JobProgram": "1234",
  "JobParameters": "<xmlString><some have=\"double quotes\" /><theresAlso aPath=\"\\path\\goes\\here\" /></xmlString>"
}
```